# SPSS Syntax to Auto relable, with specific labeling for duplicates

Tags: syntax, spss

I have a dataset with case ID's that are unique to the project, which need to be kept. However, there are cases that have the same ID, which also need to be kept. I want to create a new id that will number the cases 1 - 4000, however, utilize the same ID for the duplicates. This would show the total number of cases, not including duplicates.

---

For example:

ID      New ID

x20      1

x25     2

x30     3

x30     3

x30     3

x35     4

x40  5

---

Any suggestions on how to do this easily with syntax? I have 4000 cases & would prefer to not do it by hand & avoid any mistakes.
Thanks!
-Sherah

Answer (score 1):

```
compute NewID=1.
sort cases by ID.
if $casenum>1 NewID=lag(NewID)+(lag(ID)<>ID).
exe.
```

Comment: Same question on [Nabble](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Syntax-to-Auto-relable-with-specific-labeling-for-duplicates-td5733717.html) with a couple of different options.

Comment: Thank you for your help!